# Does admin on rest support *has_many_through* relationship with <SelectArrayInput /> Component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, admin-on-rest

In the below model, Appointment, has two foreign key properties, physicianId and patientId, that reference the primary keys in the declaring model, Physician, and the target model, Patient.

Can we modify  in such a way that 
 it shows all the patients in [chip input field](https://material.io/guidelines/components/chips.html#chips-usage) belonging to the specific Physician and also display all the patients when clicking on field in dropdown?

[image: Model]